# Where Is My Raw Query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here is my controller code;

```
$temp_table_data = $temp_table
    ->setTempTable($generated_temp_table)
    ->newQuery()
    ->with(['payment' => function ($query) use ($column_values) {
        $query->select($column_values);
    }])->get();
```

My `toSql` query is right below it;

```
    $sql = str_replace(['%', '?'], ['%%', "'%s'"], $temp_table->toSql());
    $fullSql = vsprintf($sql, $temp_table->getBindings());
    print_r($fullSql);
```

My code prints out;

```
select * from `selected_postcodes_1434968225_1`
```

Where are the details of the `payments` information that I am "with"ing? If I want to print out the raw query now, to show another developer, to get some help, what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: The eager loaded relationships are fetched in a separate query. You can use `DB::getQueryLog()` to get all run queries. (you have to enable it first though)

Comment: @lukasgeiter you should consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The eager loaded relationships are fetched in a separate query. You can use `DB::getQueryLog()` to get all run queries. Note that you have to enable it first using with `DB::enableQueryLog()`.

Another alternative is the [Laravel Debugbar package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) that shows you all queries and much more.